# How to implemented breadcrums in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, breadcrumbs

i have in trouble in using breadcrumbs for laravel,i using laravel 5.3 and when i install the package, it always fail and display error message like in the picture

[image]

If you have solution i do hope you can share to me...

Thanks

Comment: It says your laravel/framework is locked at version 5.3.29 try my answer hope it helps.

Comment: Sory, i mean laravel 5.3

Comment: So in the message error i am currently using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try to install v5.1.1

```
composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:5.1.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the requirements to run `composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:5.1.2`

```
"require": {
            "php": ">=7.1.3",
            "illuminate/support: 5.6.*",
            "illuminate/view: 5.6.*,
            "laravel/framework": "5.6.*"
        },

"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
```

Add this to your `composer.json`. Hope it helps

Comment: I am using laravel 5.3

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih can you able to copy your `composer.json` on your content?

Comment: Yes i have made it, in my content

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih now try to find at your composer.lock `"illuminate/view"` if you see it change the value to 5.6.*

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih in the image you send in your error let me clarify the full error that you got. You can see it Problem : 1 above cause you only post the last part of the error. Have a look and let me see.

Comment: @ImmanuelSaragih Post the first error scroll up further cause you can see a Problem:1 out there.

Comment: I have a new picture again

Comment: source https://packagist.org/packages/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs Breadcrumbs packages